# How do I override the django admin LogEntry model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to change the model used for the default LogEntry class so it creates a varchar rather than a clob in the database for the attribute "object_id"

The original model is defined in

> django/contrib/admin/models.py

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(_('action time'), auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.TextField(_('object id'), blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(_('object repr'), max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('action flag'))
    change_message = models.TextField(_('change message'), blank=True)
```

I want to change the definition of object_id to

```
object_id = models.Charfield(_('object id'), max_length=1000,  blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm aware that this could cause issues if someone defined a primary key on an entity which is larger than a varchar(1000), but I wouldn't want an entity with a PK defined like that so I'm happy with the limitation.

This will greatly improve the efficiency of the queries when accessing the history log.

I don't really want to hack the actual model definition, but I can't find out how to elegantly override the model definition.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django’s model fields provide an undocumented `contribute_to_class` method.
The other feature of Django we can use is the `class_prepared` signal.

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.signals import class_prepared

def add_field(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    class_prepared signal handler that checks for the model named
    MyModel as the sender, and adds a CharField
    to it.
    """
    if sender.__name__ == "MyModel":
        field = CharField("New field", max_length=100)
        field.contribute_to_class(sender, "new_field")

class_prepared.connect(add_field)
```

To override field you can simply delete original field from model:

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.signals import class_prepared

def override_field(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender.__name__ == "LogEntry":
        field = CharField('object id', max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
        sender._meta.local_fields = [f for f in sender._meta.fields if f.name != "object_id"]
        field.contribute_to_class(sender, "object_id")

class_prepared.connect(override_field)
```

I have just tested this solution by placing this code in `__init__.py` of my app. You will also need to write a custom migration:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    def __init__(self, name, app_label):
        # overriding application operated upon
        super(Migration, self).__init__(name, 'admin')

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='logentry',
            name='object_id',
            field=models.CharField('object id', max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

**Looks like it works but use it on your own risk.**

You can read more [here](http://blog.jupo.org/2011/11/10/django-model-field-injection/).

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is very interesting to know about but I don't think it quite solves the problem. It sounds like I can add a new field but I would still have the clob field in the model. From reading the link to the docs you provided there are also some downsides to do this like the management of the models through migrations.

Comment: @Nick, I have updated my answer to solve your problem. Check it out. Looks like it works but use it on your own risk. I cant predict what can crash.

Comment: Just asking, why is it not possible for me to just write the custom migration to alter the field?